# syntax directed definition for S -> '{' L '}' ; L-> L S | null

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

```
**Exercise 5.4.4**    Write L-attributed SDD's analogous to that of Example 5.19 
for the fo llowing productions, each of which represents a familiar flow-of-control 
construct , as in the programming language C. You may need to generate a three­
address statement to jump to a particular label L, in which case you should 
generate g;oto L. 
c)S -> '{' L '}' ; L-> L S | null
```

This is the question from Dragon book exercise. I am confuse here whether it is List or other. if this is the list then i have attempted in this way:

```
List = new()
List.next = S.next

and the list continue with List1,2,....n.
```

I just want to confirm whether i am going right or wrong? 
here is the book link: http://www.slideshare.net/rajarshisbaisthakurforever/dragon-book-for-compiler-2v2. the page number is 337 chapter 5 section 5.5. IMPLEMENTING L-ATTRIB UTED SDD 'S

Comment: `L` is a list of statements; each `S` is a statement. Read the note about branches carefully; it is giving you a hint about what each `S` needs to know